# How to add formula to multiple cells with already existing values in them?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table filled with hundreds of values in different cells (not coming in order, chaotic). Now I want to add 20% to each value (=x*1.2).

what formula should I use?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get the desired result is to add a new table or worksheet and copy the update formula in each cell (e.g `=A1*1.2`). You could then overwrite the old values by pasting the new values. Pasting values overwrites any old formula.

If you want to manipulate the formula of every cell, you should look into a vba solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: 
1. Write a 1.2 in an empty cell out of table. 
2. Copy this cell (1.2). 
3. Select the table with values. Right-click of the mouse, select **Paste Special -> Paste Special..-> Multiply.**  Voila!

Result: all selected values in the table were multiplied by 20%

Thanks a lot to my colleague Lina!